# Can I Left justify and Center justify two objects inside the same flex container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, justify

I have a flex-container(row), where Im looking for the first object to be left justified at a static width, and then for the next object to be centered and fill the remainder of the container.

[ (obj1) | <----------(obj2)---------> ]

I know that I could accomplish this easier with the grid styling below, but my goal here is to educate myself in flex.

`display:grid; 
grid-template-columns: 100px 1fr;`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the code snippets for the flex implementation.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.obj-a {
  background: lime;
  flex-basis: 100px;
}
.obj-b {
  background: skyblue;
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="obj-a">obj-a</div>
  <div class="obj-b">obj-b</div>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked for me, but I had to add min-width:100px. I'm sure it's got something to do with the other styling's that I have on the container. Thank you!

Comment: I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

yes this can be done in `flex`
best read is [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

you need to use 
`flex-shrink`, `flex-grow`, `flex-basis` the short form as below

`flex: shrink grow basis` ie. `flex: 1 1 auto`

below is the example I use `flex` short-form and added a border for representation purposes.

```css
* {
  borx-sizing: border-box;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 1em;
}

.flex-container .left {
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 200px;
}

.flex-container .main {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  border: 2px solid green;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="main"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have read about "beset", but I've heard that it's not widely supported, so I'm staying away from it.